# Spring Boot Fails to Connect to PostgreSQL When Username and Database Name Are the Same

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, database-connection

I'm working with Spring Boot and trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I've encountered an unusual issue where the connection fails when the username and database name are the same. This issue doesn't seem to occur when they are different.

Here's the relevant part of my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=mydatabase
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

I've checked the following:

- The database URL, username, and password are correct.
- PostgreSQL is running and accessible.
- There are no apparent network issues affecting connectivity.
- The PostgreSQL JDBC driver is included in the project dependencies.

I've also confirmed that the `pg_hba.conf` file allows connections from the host where the application is running.

Despite this, the connection fails specifically when the username and database name are the same. If I change either the username or the database name (assuming the corresponding user/db exists), the connection works.

Is there a known issue or limitation in Spring Boot or PostgreSQL that could cause this behavior? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to a conflict between the default PostgreSQL behavior and how Spring Boot configures the data source. To resolve this, you can try specifying the connection properties explicitly. Update your `application.properties` as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=mydatabase
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionInitSql=SET SEARCH_PATH TO mydatabase
```

This configuration includes setting the `driver-class-name`, disabling Hibernate's use of JDBC metadata defaults, and explicitly setting the `SEARCH_PATH` to the database name. The `SEARCH_PATH` is a PostgreSQL schema search path, and specifying it explicitly may help in cases where the username and database name are the same.

Try these configurations and see if the issue persists.